# Chrome Extension - Pass Value from content_script to popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension where my `content.js` extracts data from a webpage and sends it to `background.js` using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. The data is correctly received and logged in `background.js`.

Now, I want to pass this data from `background.js` to `popup.js` and display it in my extension's popup HTML (`popup.html`). However, I'm encountering the error "`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist`" when trying to send the data from `background.js` to `popup.js`.

How can I effectively send the data from `background.js` to `popup.js` and display it in popup.html?

Manifest - Relevant Portion

```
"action": { "default_popup": "popup.html" },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
  "background":{ "service_worker": "background.js" }
```

Content.JS

```
const name = document.querySelector('#name');    
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(name);
```

Background.JS

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);
});
```

POPUP.JS

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("Message received in popup.js:", message); 
  document.getElementById("name").textContent = message;           
});
```

POPUP.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="name"></p>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because the popup can't receive anything when it's not running. Simply use [executeScript in popup script](/a/67227376), no need for the background script or content_scripts.